# Is the New Testament Greek οὖν the same as the English “therefore”?

Tags: greek

The Bible Greek word οὖν is often translated as *therefore*. However, grammatically, οὖν is a conjunction while the English *therefore* is an adverb. Semantically, *therefore* carries a strong sense of logical consequence. A happens; therefore B happens as a result.

The Greek οὖν seems to be more ambiguous than that.

Should we automatically associate logical conclusion to it as many preachers claim that we should?

Comment: At least in classical Greek there seems to be a variety of nuances, as you say: https://logeion.uchicago.edu/οὖν; but that is not necessarily conclusive evidence for how the word was used 4-500 years later in Biblical Greek.

Comment: οὖν is an adverb, not a conjunction.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You guys are great. From your comments, I did some more googling around and found https://www.billmounce.com/monday-with-mounce/when-%CE%BF%E1%BD%94%CE%BD-doesn%E2%80%99t-mean-%E2%80%9Ctherefore%E2%80%9D-john-11-6

Comment: For NT Greek the place to look is Bauer et al. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%27s_Lexicon). If you can find a library that is open.

Comment: Serves the function of "actually";  "so..."; "so now";  "so, then"., in conversational English.